# How do i view xml when i ship fedex?

Tags: xml, fedex

is there a way to retrieve the fedex xml that is being sent?

```
log.info("*** GENERATING TRACKING :: " + service.getShipServicePortAddress()
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO.  Please read [ask] to get a better outcome.  Your question pretty much has no relevant information.

Comment: i'm trying to figure out which property in Open Declaration com.fedex.ship.stub.ProcessShipmentRequest will provide me with writing the webservice request to the log